# Using a dictionary comprehension with an included string split operation

Tags: python, regex, string, split, dictionary-comprehension

Consider a tiny properties parser snippet:

```
testx="""var1 = foo
         var2 = bar"""

dd = { l.split('=')[0].strip():l.split('=')[1].strip() for l in testx.split('\n')} 
print(dd)
# {'var1': 'foo', 'var2': 'bar'}
```

That works , but is ugly due to the double invocation of "split" in `l.split('=')[0].strip():l.split('=')[1].strip()`
. How can the dictionary comprehension be changed to only need to split once and then build the dict entries as:

```
l[0].strip():l[1].strip()
```

Does that refactoring require a nested for comprehension or a different way of constructing a single level comprehension?

Comment: The term is not "for comprehension", you are working with a *dictionary comprehension*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  fair enough - fixed in tags and fixing in body

Comment: Anyway, if you are on very recent versions of Python, you can use an assignment expression to avoid calling `l.split("=")` multiple times unnecessarily. Otherwise it's probably just best to do a normal for-loop. There are hacky ways to do it without that but they get ugly, which removes the only advantage of dictionary comprehensions: clarity and convenience

Comment: ah you mean the walrus operator of 3.9 . Yes i'm on 3.9 and so that is an option.  But can this be done using a nested comprehension?  I really am disappointed with python's lack of functional programming and given the comprehensions are the only thing similar would like to see how to gain more flexibility in their use.  For loops are like 2009 or earlier for me - before I learnt scala.

Comment: If you don't like for-loops, just don't use Python. For loops are extremely Pythonic. The language itself is very much an imperative language, which borrows some constructs from functional programming languages like Haskell (e.g. list comprehensions, more recently, pattern matching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Python >= 3.8 this is exactly why assignment expressions were added:

```
>>> {(parts:=l.split('='))[0].strip(): parts[1].strip() for l in testx.split("\n")}
{'var1': 'foo', 'var2': 'bar'}
```

Prior to this, you could do something like:

```
>>> {key.strip():value.strip() for l in testx.split('\n') for key, value in [l.split("=")]}
{'var1': 'foo', 'var2': 'bar'}
```

Which honestly, I find more readable.

But honestly, these are both still pretty unreadable to me. At the end of the day, I don't think you can beat:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for l in testx.split("\n"):
...     key, value = l.split("=")
...     result[key.strip()] = value.strip()
...
>>> result
{'var1': 'foo', 'var2': 'bar'}
```

#### EDIT

Note, the `for <target list> in [<expression>]` idiom has actually been *optimized* in Python 3.9:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations

> Optimized the idiom for assignment a temporary variable in
> comprehensions. Now `for y in [expr]` in comprehensions is as fast as a
> simple assignment `y = expr`. For example:
>
> `sums = [s for s in [0] for x in data for s in [s + x]]`
>
> Unlike the `:=` operator this idiom does not leak a variable to the
> outer scope.

Compare the bytecode in Pyhton 3.8 vs Pyhton 3.9, you'll notice there is no nested iteration in the Python 3.9 version:

Python 3.8:

```
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan  8 2020, 16:15:59)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('{k:v for l in "a b|c d".split("|") for k,v in [l.split()]}')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <dictcomp> at 0x7fdbd6249d40, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<dictcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a b|c d')
              8 LOAD_METHOD              0 (split)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('|')
             12 CALL_METHOD              1
             14 GET_ITER
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <dictcomp> at 0x7fdbd6249d40, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                30 (to 36)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (l)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (l)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              0 (split)
             12 CALL_METHOD              0
             14 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             16 GET_ITER
        >>   18 FOR_ITER                14 (to 34)
             20 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             22 STORE_FAST               2 (k)
             24 STORE_FAST               3 (v)
             26 LOAD_FAST                2 (k)
             28 LOAD_FAST                3 (v)
             30 MAP_ADD                  3
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           18
        >>   34 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   36 RETURN_VALUE
```

Versus Python 3.9:

```
Python 3.9.0 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 14 2020, 22:56:29)
[Clang 10.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('{k:v for l in "a b|c d".split("|") for k,v in [l.split()]}')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <dictcomp> at 0x7fb3587d1870, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<dictcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a b|c d')
              8 LOAD_METHOD              0 (split)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('|')
             12 CALL_METHOD              1
             14 GET_ITER
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <dictcomp> at 0x7fb3587d1870, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                22 (to 28)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (l)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (l)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              0 (split)
             12 CALL_METHOD              0
             14 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             16 STORE_FAST               2 (k)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (v)
             20 LOAD_FAST                2 (k)
             22 LOAD_FAST                3 (v)
             24 MAP_ADD                  2
             26 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Thx for reminding about the walrus operator and i'll upvote for that.  But the main intent of my question is to understand better how to structure a problem within the constraints of for/dictionary comprehensions.   That second "paragaph" of code is 2009-ish for me (pre-functional programming in scala). Yes I know that seems to be the popular way to program in nonfunctional python but hold out hope for an alternative.

Comment: @StephenBoesch I have edited to have another approach. At the end of the day though, you are working against the language. If you don't like imperative programming, you probably just shouldn't use Python. Python is absolutely *not* a functional programming language, especially CPython (e.g. no tail-call optimization, which very much hinders efficient functional programming, also, the data structures are not tailored towards functional programming, so lists are array lists, not cons lists, no built-in persistent data structures)

Comment: Thanks for that input.  The libraries I need are in python: deep learning and machine learning.  Question for you: is it your take there is no way to structure the above in a  single or doubly nested comprehension without using a clever modification (such as via walrus operator or regex) ?  I mean is the comprehension structure not able to solve the problem directly

Comment: @StephenBoesch I posted one... please re-read my question I edited it. It is a more general approach than the walrus operator, basically, `for <target list> in whatever` is a hidden assignment, so you can arbitrarily do an assignment by using `for <target list> in [<some expression>]`.

Comment: Ah! I just re-read your walrus operator piece. Yes I think that does solve it.  Out of curiosity : before 3.8 brought along the walrus/assignment operator- would there be no way to solve this?  I'm trying to distinguish between it being my weakness (not able to construct a more involved comprehension properly) and the language limitation.

Comment: @StephenBoesch You could always do the `for <target list> in [<some expression>]` trick, but it's the sort of thing that should never pass a decent code review, both options I've pointed above I would not accept if they were in a PR I was reviewing, for example. I would insist on the regular for-loop

Comment: Oh now I see the second part of your rewrite: it exactly answers my last comment. Thanks so much!  (And yes that's challenging to figure out). The crux there (that I did not know how to do ) is the brackets [] around the inner nested loop `[l.split("=")]`.

Comment: @StephenBoesch well, the crux is creating *some* iterable to loop over, a list, tuple, etc would all work. I think the `[<expression>]` list approach is the most readable

Comment: Thanks for the update on the documentation. Also I had forgotten that the walrus operator "leaks" the variable. I'd turn that around often enough and say it "exposes" / "publishes" the variable to the outer scope: it's sometimes handy! But in any case good to understand the behavior and design accordingly

Comment: This is one of the most helpful answers I have received in a long while. thx

Comment: and you made the answer _even better_  I've pip'ed `dis` now - a tool/toy for viewing the generated code

Comment: @StephenBoesch sorry, what do you mean by "pip'ed `dis`"? `dis` is part of the standard library... you should not `pip` it and I woudl be concered if you *did* install something like `pip install dis`... this is super sketch: https://pypi.org/project/dis/ might be malware

Comment: Thx for that info - I did pip install it since was unaware it's std library. Seems to work OK (got same result as you show for 3.9 above) but I won't do pip on it in the future.

Comment: @StephenBoesch definitely you should uninstall that. "it works ok" makes it *even more suspicious*. If it *didn't* work it is probably just a poorly though-out name for some package, if it *works the same as the standard library* then it increases the chances that it is actually malware. EDIT: looking at the source, it seems innocuous, someone was probably just playing around with python packaging. But you should still probably remove that.

Comment: fyi after the uninstall it says `dis is not defined` ;)  No worries : if I really need `dis` I'll use a different computer for a moment

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
testx="""var1 = foo
         var2 = bar"""

dct = dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*=\s*(\S+)', testx))
print(dct)
# {'var1': 'foo', 'var2': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Thx that's clever. I am more interested actually in a way to generalize the question about how to tease apart a list _using the split() construct_  by proper application of nested/(or not?) comprehensions.   For comprehensions are all we have in python and they have not worked v well for me so far. I crave the ability to do doubly and triply nested operations with more ease.  I have updated the tags to reflect that emphasis.